# In Alfresco, how do I access variables of workflow instance from java script?

Tags: alfresco

For debugging purposes I want to access variables of some workflow. I obtain the instance of workflow using this code:

```
var workflowInstance = workflow.getDefinition("some id");
```

How do I access variables in `workflowInstance`? Is it possible to manipulate those variables from java script (e.g. from JavaScript Console)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you're not getting the workflow instance right: you're really getting the workflow definition. In order to get the instance, you must invoke

```
var instance = workflow.getInstance(instanceId);
```

But then, properties are set on Tasks, so if you know the task ID you could directly go for

```
var task = workflow.getTask(taskId);
var props = task.getProperties();
```

You can find a reference of the available API [on the wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Workflow_JavaScript_API).

Comment: If I have instance, how do I get Tasks associated with that instance?